# How to tweak official Helm charts to prevent deploying some of the resources

Tags: redis, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I want to deploy Redis in `Standalone` mode and I believe I don't need a master `Service` resource type. How can I change default `values.yaml` to prevent deploying master Service resource?
Here is the output of `kubectl get all -n redis-ns`:

```
NAME                    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/go-redis-master-0   0/1     Running   0          20s

NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
service/go-redis-headless   ClusterIP   None            <none>        6379/TCP   20s
service/go-redis-master     ClusterIP   10.97.160.122   <none>        6379/TCP   20s

NAME                               READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/go-redis-master   0/1     20s
```

recap: I want to change Helm default values to prevent deploying `go-redis-master` Service. I only need one Headless Service.

Comment: can you provide more details like your values.yaml and service manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing some default values in Redis Helm Chart files:

```
architecture: replication => architecture: standalone
auth.enabled: true => auth.enabled: false
auth.sentinel: true => auth.sentinel: false
```

Remove `helm-app/templates/master/service.yaml` file to deploy Redis with one Headless Service.

Deploy with the command below:

```
$ helm install go-redis -f helm-folder/redis/values.yaml helm-folder/redis --namespace redis-ns
```